# CUDA: Using realloc inside kernel

Tags: cuda

I know that it is possible to use `malloc` inside the kernel to allocate memory on GPU's global memory. Is it also possible to use `realloc`?

Comment: Where did you get that information? AFAIK there is no such thing as memory management inside a kernel. You have to prepare everything upfront.

Comment: malloc and free are supported according to the 3.2 programming guide.

Comment: Also `new` and `delete` since 4.0

Answer (score 5):

You could write you own realloc device function for your data type.

Just allocate the new space for a new array, copy the old values to the new, free the old array space, return the new with more space.

Approximately like the following code fragment:

```
__device__ MY_TYPE* myrealloc(int oldsize, int newsize, MY_TYPE* old)
{
    MY_TYPE* newT = (MY_TYPE*) malloc (newsize*sizeof(MY_TYPE));

    int i;

    for(i=0; i<oldsize; i++)
    {
        newT[i] = old[i];
    }

    free(old);
    return newT;
}
```

But be sure to call it, if you really need it. Also add proper error checking.

Comment: if newsize < oldsize, the loop should be until newsize right? also, old can be null.

Answer (score 4):

In the Cuda Programming Guide, when they introduce `malloc` and `free` functions, there is no mention of `realloc`. I would assume that it does not exist.

If you want to know it for sure, why don't you write a simple kernel and try using it?