# CUDA Dynamic memory allocation in kernel

Tags: memory, cuda

There are two arrays named A and B, they are corresponding to each other, and their space are allocated during the kernels running. the details of A and B are that A[i] is the position and B[i] is value.All the threads do the things below:

1. If the current thread's data is in the arrays update B,
2. Else expanding A and B, and insert the current thread's data into the arrays.
3. The initial size of A and B are zero.

Is the upper implementing supported by CUDA?

Comment: Could you please clarify point #1?

Comment: point #1 means that A[i] and B[i] store the position and value of the i-th element, current thread may update B[i], if the position of current thread's element is in array A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning point #2, you would need something like C++'s `realloc()`, which, as long as I know, is not supported by CUDA. You can write your own `realloc()` according to this post

[CUDA: Using realloc inside kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322583/cuda-using-realloc-inside-kernel)

but I do not know how efficient will be this solution.

Alternatively, you should pre-allocate a "large" amount of global memory to be able to account for the worst case memory occupation scenario.

Comment: Thanks a lot! another question is how to guarantee atomic operation? if there are one more threads update A and B at the same time.

Comment: Have a look at the CUDA C Programming Guide, Section B.11. There you will find information on how using atomic operations in CUDA.

Comment: the atomic operations in Section B.11 are used for exact number of global memory or shared memory, such as B[i]; I want to guarantee atomic operation for the whole array, such as the other thread is refused to access the array while one thread is accessing the array.

Comment: You might consider using a critical section to control access to the array but there are challenges and difficulties. Search on cuda critical section in the upper right corner

Comment: the threads in the same block should access the critical section so this will lead to deadlock.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned there would be challenges and difficulties.  You could consider using a critical section to manage inter-block access, while using the ordinary threadblock communications methods (shared memory, `__syncthreads()`, etc.) to handle arbitration within a threadblock.